# Calling method in java arraylist which contains obects created by class with generic arguments

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

Calling the method name `sales()` in codes below cannot be accessed.
The objects in arraylist are the class Group1`which uses generic arguments. And,`division_a.list.get(0)`shoud have the Group1 object. And,`division_a.list.get(0).getComponent()`should return`Component1`object. Then the`sales()`method should be usable. 
 But, the exception message shows "The method`sales()` is undefined for the type capture#2-of ?"  It's a mystry for me that **division_a.list.get(0).getComponent() does not return objects of Component1 class**, although the return type is defined as "public T getComponent().."

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Division_a {
    public ArrayList<Group1<?>> list=null;

    public Division_a() {
        list=new ArrayList();
    }

    public void put(Group1<?> group1) {
        list.add(group1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Group1<Component1> groupcomponent1 = new Group1<>(new Component1());
        Division_a division_a = new Division_a();
        division_a.put(groupcomponent1);
        division_a.list.get(0).getComponent().sales(); //excetion occur
    }

}

class Component1 {
    public void sales() {
        System.out.println("component1 sold");
    }
}   

class Group1<T> {

    public T component; 

    Group1(T component){
        this.component=component; 
    }


    public T getComponent() {       //return type T
        return component;
    }

    public void setComponent(T component) {
        this.component=component;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `sales` method is only available in `Component1`. So if you need to call that method you should have either `Component1` of any subtype of that. If you want to make it either `Component1` or a subtype of it then you have to use a bounded wildcard instead of using an unbounded wildcard which can literally be anything. Here's the corrected code.

```
public ArrayList<Group1<? extends Component1>> list = null;

public void put(Group1<? extends Component1> group1) {
    list.add(group1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you  for your reply. But  it's mystry that division_a.list.get(0).getComponent() does not return objects of Component1 class, although the return type is defined as "public T getComponent().."

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to understand how class erasure works in java.  The generic information is never actually passed to the container, it's only enforced on the compiler side.  [Here is a good tutorial explaining it](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure).

The easiest way to accomplish what you're looking to accomplish is to have an appropriate interface, like:

```
public interface WithSales {
    Sales sales();
}
```

and make sure that your components implmeent them.  Then you declare your wrappers appropriately, so your list declaration would look like:

```
public List<Group1<? extends WithSales>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then the rest of your code would work fine as long as all of the instances of **Component** implement **WithSales**